# Image Puzzle game help

Tags: android, algorithm

I made an app in Android, in which I put twelve buttons. When you click on a button, it will show you an image on the button. It's like an image puzzle game, with two buttons containing one image.

If the images match, then the game continues, but if the images do not match, it will disappear.

The only thing that I don't understand is what code and logic I should use if the image does not match and it will disappear.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make something disappear and take up no space, you can set its visibility to 8 (which is invisible). Here I'm making everything inside a layout invisible.

```
        LinearLayout buttonbox = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.storybox);
        buttonbox.setVisibility(8);
```

You can change the visibility of any kind of view. [Here's the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29).

Comment: You should never use "magic numbers" like the `8` there. Android provides constants that should be passed in like `View.INVISIBLE`. The `8` that you provide actually maps to `View.GONE`. This improves code readability for whoever has to maintain the code and allows those constants to have their value changed without affecting your code.